# Drupal - New groups/fields not showing for custom content types

Tags: php, drupal

I've created a couple new Content Types (City, Property) through the content types admin interface, and added some custom fields to those content types (Latitude, Longitude, Image, etc.).

Now, when I go to create new content, I don't see any of the fields I've added; all I'm seeing are the default fields.

Is there an additional step that I'm missing here?  I'm using Drupal 6.16.

Comment: I assume by "create new content" you're choosing one of the content types that you set up, as opposed to a default option like "Page," is that right?

Comment: Definitely.  So I choose the 'City' type, but see none of the custom fields that I've added.

Answer (score 3):

Ah ha!  It was a permissions issue.  My account was set to be an admin account, but the admin account type was missing quite a few permissions related to the CCK.